# Любые вхождения на месте звездочки

Tags: php

У меня есть код

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'site-*') echo 'True';
```

Как вместо * подставлять разные значения и чтобы код срабатывал?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос взялся с моего прошлого ответа, дело в том что сама структура обработки, не такая, обработку вы настраиваете сами, а это просто пример. Но вообще такое решесеться получением и разделение URL запроса, для MVC роутинга. 
Вот тут [подробнее](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/150267/).

Comment: паттерн HMVC, по моему личному опыту, кажется куда более перспективным и имеет ряд крутых плюшек перед MVC.

Comment: Без условно это так,  но новичку легче начинать с MVC.